# Catching key on real time

Tags: c, unix, sleep

i Want to catch keyboard key on a real time game, for example im printing each 0,3s with usleep(300000) something like that

```
// #####
// ##a##
// #####
```

and I want to move my 'a' arround with the directional keyboard key (left, right...) the problem is each time I call read the program is paused till I enter a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. multi-threading
2. asynchronous I/O

Comment: well, I guess its unfeasible with only read() then, im gonna search some new way

Comment: No need to search for "some new way", I've already told you the two possible ways.

Comment: im gonna go for the asynchronous by modifying my term

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.

Comment: readline is for command-line applications; I don't think it helps with this use case.